# MPI and DLL(SO) functions

Tags: c++, windows, cluster-computing, hpc

New to MPI, currently I dont have a super computer (yet) to play with, one thing I dont know is, how is DLL/SO handled in cluster computing? Can we use DLL/SO the same way we used them on a PC?

Why there are so few supercomputer that support Windows HPC OS instead of Linux? Currently I think programming software on windows is much easier thanks to visual studio, but too bad it looks like for cluster-computing, linux is the first choice at the moment.

Comment: For your first question: Short answer is yes.  (Although I'm confused by why you would even suspect it wouldn't?).

Comment: For the second question, Perhaps you should peek at the [Top500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top500) chart of super computers and their OS choice. People use what works *best* for them when they have a choice; what simply works for them when they don't.

Comment: Your second question is somewhat inappropriate for Stack Overflow since it only asks for *opinions* that are not directly related to programming. My *opinion* is that it's primarily about two things. Price being one. (Compare the cost of Windows Server OS vs Free Linux). The other reason is simply because Unix has a longer history distributed computing

Comment: Does Windows HPC Server support high performance parallel filesystems like Lustre? Are advanced parallel debuggers like TotalView or Allinea DDT available for Windows? Does large-scale parallel profilers like Scalasca support Windows MPI libraries? How much easier is to maintain a large and expensive Windows installation than to use free tools like xCAT to maintain Linux clusters? Find out the answers to these simple questions and you might answer your second question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what you've already been told in the comments to your question:

a) I think that one part of the reason for Linux's dominance in the world of supercomputing is that it is open-source.  Once you've developed the hardware for your 10^6-CPU behemoth you might want to tweak the o/s a bit to optimise it for the particularly cool features you've designed and built in.

b) If you like developing under Visual Studio but want to run your codes on a supercomputer you can do what I do: develop code under Visual Studio and run code on a supercomputer. (Actually, my employers don't really have a supercomputer, just a very large cluster or two but *meh*.)

I have a desktop PC with twin quad-core CPUs, an installation of VS, the Intel Fortran compiler and a variety of Intel libraries such as the MKL.  I also have an installation of the Intel MPI development kit and run-time for the PC so I can run MPI programs on my PC while I develop them.

Then, when I want to move the codes into production, I `make` them on the cluster (where we have the same compiler and libraries) and away they go.  We stick rigidly to language standards, so we don't build in portability problems.

So, I don't see why you should have to ditch Visual Studio if you want to work on supercomputer codes.  Sure, you'll need to acquire some familiarity with `make` and a programmer's editor on the Linux side of things, but they're no more difficult to come to terms with than their equivalents once were for you on Windows.

Comment: Yes, thats a way to walk around it, however it will require quite abit maintenance to keep consistence between platforms. For instance, the pthread libs tend to behave differently in windows and linux OSs, althrough OpenMP is better in this regard, but it seems that it cannot offer the rich functionality pthread can.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't touch pthreads with a bargepole so the issue you raise is not a problem for me but you're right, differences between platforms can make development more difficult. For me the burden of maintaining codes and development tools across platforms is slight and the benefits great.